# Worklight Remote disable feature with TestFlight store

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, testflight

I'm setting the remote disable feature on WL Production env as we have two version of the app (1.0) and (1.0.1).

[image]

Our pilot users are running 1.0 and I need to notify to get the new version 1.0.1 from TestFlight.

[image]

I'm unable to find the URL that I need to set in WL console to direct the users to the newer version of the app.

WL version 6.2.0.1

The app has not been submitted to the app store yet and it is still for pilot testing.

any idea where can I find the external URL for my app on TestFlight so I can direct the users to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TestFlight is a relatively new Apple feature, and there is no built-in support for it.

As an alternative what you could do is instead send a Remote Notify message saying that "you will soon receive an update for the application from the TestFlight application".

Because when using TestFlight, updates to the app arrive to that update, from which the user taps on "update" in order to update the app. You do not go to any server per se (like an app store).